# Method isnt being found when called in the main method java

Tags: java, class, methods

I created a method to check all the teams in the array of teams and see whos winning percentage was the highest. once the loop found the highest winning perecentage, its supposed to return the team with that winning percentage. when i call a simple line of code in the main method,

```
System.out.println("The team with the highest winning percentage is: " +highest(tm));
```

i get a compiling error saying it cannot find the method highest. its static so it can communicate with the main method for the array of teams tm. if im not understanding something please explain to me my misconception.

```
public class teams{
    public static void main(String [] argv){
        /*Team team1 = new Team("knicks");
        Team team2 = new Team("nets");
        team1.play(team2);
        team1.play(team2);
        team2.play(team1);
        team2.printrecord();
        team1.printrecord();
        team2.winpercent();*/
        String[] teamnames = {"knicks", "nets", "lakers", "celtics", "heat", "spurs"};
        Team[] tm = new Team[teamnames.length]; // creates an array of teams

        for (int i=0;i<teamnames.length;i++){       // assigns a team to each string in teamnames
            tm[i] = new Team(teamnames[i]);
        }//for

        for (int i=0;i<teamnames.length;i++){       //nested for loop to have each team play another team once
            for(int k=i+1; k<teamnames.length;k++){
                if(k!=i)
                    tm[i].play(tm[k]);
            }//nestedfor
        }//for

        System.out.println("The team with the highest winning percent is: " +highest(tm));

    }//main
}//teams

class Team{
    double wins; 
    double losses;
    double winningpercent;
    String name;

    public Team(String n){
        name = n;
        wins = 0;
        losses = 0;
        winningpercent = 0;
    }//constructor

    public void lose(){
        losses++;
    }//losses

    public void win(){
        wins++;
    }//wins

    public void printrecord(){
        System.out.println("The W-L record for the " +name+ " is: " +String.format("%d",(long)wins)+"-"+String.format("%d",(long)losses));
    }

    public void play(Team j){
        if((Math.random())<0.5){
            System.out.println("The "+j.name+" Have Won!");
            j.win();
            this.lose();
        }//if
        else {
            System.out.println("The "+name+" Have Won!");
            this.win();
            j.lose();
        }//else
    }//play

    public double winpercent(){
        double winningpercentage = (wins/(losses+wins))* 100;
        System.out.println("The Winning percentage for the " +name+" is: " +winningpercentage+"%");
        this.winningpercent = winningpercentage;
        return winningpercentage;
    }//winningpercent

    public static String highest(Team[] tm){
        String highest = "";
        for (int i=0;i<tm.length;i++){
            for(int k=i+1;k<tm.length;k++){
                if (k!=i && tm[i].winningpercent > tm[k].winningpercent)
                    highest = tm[i].name;
            }//nestedforloop
        }//forloop
        return highest;
    }//highest  

}//Team
```

Comment: The method `highest` in the `team` class is not `static`. You need an instance of the `team` class. `new team().highest(tm)`

Comment: i made the method static and it still gave me the same error. but i understand why i have to make it a new instance

Comment: @BenjiWeiss-Because your static method can't have parameter of type `Team`,these methods are loaded with the loading of class! No object OR instances are loaded by the time!

Comment: if you make the method `static` you can access it by the `class name` `Team.highest(tm)`. See the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First, that method isn't static. So, this

```
public String highest(Team[] tm){
```

should be

```
public static String highest(Team[] tm){
```

Then you need to use the class name (or `import static` the method) -

```
System.out.println("The team with the highest winning percent is: " +
    Team.highest(tm));
```

Comment: ok now that i got it compile, its able to run but the output in that line is an empty string..

Comment: Your fields are never updated. Change `if (k!=i && tm[i].winningpercent > tm[k].winningpercent)` to `if (k!=i && tm[i].winpercent() > tm[k].winpercent())`

Comment: ok thank you, youve been very helpful. im not sure why its giving me the wrong team though, i run it.. it says the celtics have the highest % when they won 3 games, yet in the same run, the lakers won 4 games..meaning the lakers should have been the output.. any insight? im trying to find out why its giving me the wrong outcome but i cant seem to find it

Comment: @BenjiWeiss Override `toString()` in Team, and use `Arrays.toString()` to print your teams. Your assumption must be incorrect.

Comment: i figured it out, simple misconception, just because the lakers won more games, doesnt mean their winning percent is higher bc they lost more games than the celtics as well.